# How to kill the laravel queue:listen --queue=notification?

Tags: laravel

For a cron job I am using following code in laravel 5.1 and run the command in every 1 min. But even though after stopping cronjob from crontab the laravel code still executes. ?

```
$this->call('queue:listen', [
    '--queue' => 'notification-emails','--timeout'=>'30'
]);
```

what could be the problem ? How can I stop this queue listen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably looking for `queue:work` which will stop, when no more jobs left, meanwhile `queue:listen` will persist.

If You want to kill existing process - You have to do it manually, because there is no command in laravel to kill all queue:listen processes.
Keep in mind, that You will not find process like `artisan queue:listen`, You have to look for `artisan schedule:run` because `queue:listen`, when called internally, will not create separate process.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I kill already run queue:listen --queue=notification-emails  manually?

Comment: @KabindraSimkhada You have to do it manually. First type `ps aux | grep artisan` in Your system's console, then look for matching process ID and type `kill -9 ID`. That ID will be in second column of `ps aux` output.